# Mysql how to display some informations using select

Tags: mysql

im complete begginner and need help with this,

I need to display 5 youngest creatures who have type=food in their inventory

people and inventory are different tables. Please use the basic structure and commands, im begginer and
I would love to try to understand.

I have 3 tables inventory, creatures and resources.
columnes in inventory:
inventoryid, creatureid,resourceid,quantity
columnes in resources:
resourceid,name,weight,quantity,dateofacquisiton,type
columnes in creatures:
creatureid,name,type,bdate,weight,liftingcapacity

i tried
SELECT creature.name FROM creature,resource where resource.type = 'food' ORDER BY bdate ASC LIMIT 5;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query for latest 5 entries than order by should be `DESC`.

`select "ColumnName" from "TableName" where type = "food" order by "ColumnName" desc limit 5`